# Processor multiplier in Java

Tags: java, jna, oshi

I'm using OSHI Hardware Information library to show details of hardware. 
I have i5-4690K basic 3,5GHz overcloked to 4,5GHz and I can only show the basic 3,5GHz. 
Is it possible with OSHI or with JNA to get clock and multiplier to show this overclocked value 4,5Ghz?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library - just a note - you may want to try to contact the authors directly, if you don't get a response here. It looks like the library is on gitlab at https://github.com/oshi/oshi/

Comment: Yes it is, I think author didn't implement this in his project so I'm mainly curious if I can get this data using JNA or in other way.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/218567/any-way-to-check-the-clock-speed-of-my-processor - you can always run an external program from Java and parse the output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the primary author of the OSHI library.  [Issue #418 on the github site](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues/418) directly answers your question, with a comment showing how the value can be retrieved on various operating systems:

For Windows we can get this from Win32_Processor (CurrentClockSpeed, MaxClockSpeed).  OSHI has a WMIUtil class that can make this easier for you to do inside Java.

macOS has a sysctl() call hw.cpufrequency and hw.cpufrequency_max.  There are ample other examples of sysctl() calls.

Linux lscpu command has a CPU MHz field.  You'll have to text-parse this.  There may be other /proc filesystem alternatives which are faster.

FreeBSD has sysctl() call for dev.cpu.0.freq

Solaris has kstat cpu_info:0:cpu_info0:clock_MHz (or current_clock_Hz).   OSHI has a Kstatutil.

This has not (yet) been implemented into OSHI because it was waiting on a (recently completed) issue to count packages, but it's possible to do now and we welcome pull requests. This particular one is very accessible to implement, and if you solve it for yourself you can give back to the community.

**UPDATE:** As of version 4.0.0 there is now a method to get CPU frequency via native calls.  However, it only reports what the OS has chosen to report which may not be accurate.  The true value requires kernel-level driver support available via third party programs (e.g., CPU-Z, OpenHardwareMonitor) but is not possible to obtain in Java via JNA.